# Pass node js variable to ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a post request in node js file "index.js"

```
this.app.post('/profile', (req, res) => {                        
            let password = req.body.password;            
            let newWallet = operator.createWalletFromPassword(password);
            let projectedWallet = projectWallet(newWallet);
            res.render('profile.ejs', {
                user : req.user,
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(projectedWallet));        
        });
```

And in profile.ejs to show for client see, I have: THIS IS FULL CODE THAT I JUST EDIT AS REQUESTED.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Node Authentication</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; word-wrap:break-word; }
    </style>
</head>
<br>
   <%- include header %>

   <div class="container">

    <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h1><span class="fa fa-anchor"></span> Profile Page</h1>
        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Logout</a>
        <form action="/profile" method="get">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" id="sub" >test</button>
        </form> 
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <!-- LOCAL INFORMATION -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well">
                <h3><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Local</h3>
                    <form action="/profile" method="post">
                        <p>                                                    
                            <strong>id</strong>: <%= user.id %><br>
                            <strong>username</strong>: <%= user.username %><br>
                            <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.password %>

                        </p>                                               
                        <textarea id="myTextArea" cols=50 rows=10><%= data %>
                        </textarea>
                        <!-- these fields will be sent to server -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%= user.username %>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<%= user.password %>">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" id="sub" >Wallet</button>
                    </form>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
    <%- include footer %>
```

What I want is to put value of "`projectedWallet`" in post request to textarea in ejs file, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Somebody help me, please!!!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to feed `projectedWallet` into the textarea through EJS like so:

***index.js***

```
this.app.post('/profile', (req, res) => {                        
  let password = req.body.password;            
  let newWallet = operator.createWalletFromPassword(password);
  let projectedWallet = projectWallet(newWallet);
  res.render('profile.ejs', {
    user : req.user,

    // We are now feeding your EJS template another variable
    projectedWallet : JSON.stringify(projectedWallet),
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(projectedWallet));        
});
```

... and use it within the textarea inside your template

***profile.ejs***

```
<form action="/profile" method="post">
  <p>                                                    
   <strong>id</strong>: <%= user.id %><br>
   <strong>username</strong>: <%= user.username %><br>
   <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.password %>                         
  </p>                                               
  <textarea id="myTextArea" cols=50 rows=10>

    <!-- We now populate the template with the sent variable -->
    <%= projectedWallet %>

  </textarea>
  <!-- these fields will be sent to server -->
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%= user.username %>">
  <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<%= user.password %>">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Wallet</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: It not work! An error appear: <%= projectedWallet %> 39| 40| 41| projectedWallet is not defined

Comment: @Meowth2018 I notice you have `res.render('profile.ejs', ...)` in your *index.js* file. You are rendering *profile.ejs*, not *index.ejs*. Where are you rendering *index.ejs*?

Comment: sorry, my mistake typing. the file I'm using is profile.ejs, not index.ejs

Comment: but it's not a problem, problem is that after rendering, projectedWallet is not defined in profile.ejs

Comment: Are you sure that `projectedWallet` is always defined? And, may I ask what version of EJS you are using?

Comment: I edit code as you said above. What do you means "projectedWallet is always defined"? I declared it in let projectedWallet = projectWallet(newWallet); and call it like you said. But it still not return error projectWallet is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the variable in response's local variables and then use it at frontend side (EJs in this case).

updated code::

**index.js**

```
this.app.post('/profile', (req, res) => {                        
            let password = req.body.password;            
            let newWallet = operator.createWalletFromPassword(password);
            let projectedWallet = projectWallet(newWallet);
            //added line
            res.locals.projectedWallet =  projectedWallet
            res.render('profile.ejs', {
                user : req.user,
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(projectedWallet));        
        });
```

**profile.ejs**

```
<form action="/profile" method="post">
    <p>                                                    
        <strong>id</strong>: <%= user.id %><br>
        <strong>username</strong>: <%= user.username %><br>
        <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.password %>                         
    </p>   
      <!-- updated line -->                                  
    <textarea id="myTextArea" cols=50 rows=10><%=projectedWallet %>
    </textarea>
    <!-- these fields will be sent to server -->
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%= user.username %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<%= user.password %>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Wallet</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It still return an rerror "projectedWallet is not defined"

Comment: help me, please!

Comment: please share your entire index.js file.

Comment: please, look at my question. I just edited as you requested. Please help me! Some place said that I have to declare "middleware functions" but I really don't know where to start or how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the variable (**projectedWallet**) is defined, in the `.get` request you are not sending the **projectedWallet** as a parameter, so that's why you are getting the error

```
<% if(typeof projectedWallet !== 'undefined') { %>
   <p><%= projectedWallet %></p>
<% } %>
```

If you render a view multiple times sometimes with variables and others without, you need to add a condition and check if that variable exist for each render